# DRF Router issue with namespace

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am having a hell of a time getting the reverse function to work with my DRF implementation. Here is my urls.py, which i would assume the following reverse to work for:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'compressors', views.CompressorViewSet, base_name='compressors')
from django.urls import include, path
# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls, namespace='router')),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', 
namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

And then

```
reverse('router:compressors', kwargs)
```

What am I missing? I am getting a app_name not provided, which when added to this file does not help. Is there a way for me to put an app_name to the router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out its just hard to find exactly how the use basename, I did not append '-list' to my reverse. It should have been the following, hope this helps others:

```
reverse('router:compressors-list')
```

Comment: Glad you solved your issue, just thought I'd add a recommendation for [django_extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions), which adds a management command you can run `python manage.py show_urls` to print out all your urls, including: The view class path (my_app.views.MyView), the actual url path (/apps/my-app/:url_kwarg), and the route name (router:comporessors-list)

Comment: @ARJMP Thanks fam! I have that installed but had no idea of that feature :) Would have made this so much easier!